# Send Key not working in Appium with Python

Tags: appium-android, python-appium

[I have used three types of send keys but still it is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmUS0.png)

Comment: Please add more information, what issue you are facing ?

Comment: when I am trying to click on the search button I am not able to search any product (This error  is getting -->Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\appium project\First test.py", line 42, in <module>
    e.sendKeys("Iphone")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendKeys')

Answer (score 0):

On inspection, you are setting

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(your xpath).click()
```

Since you are using `.click()` it will assign `None` to `e`. You should put simply

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(your xpath)
```

In the future, please post your code in the question instead of linking an image.

Comment: I have tried this one still not working.                                                                                                        e=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.LinearLayout[@content-desc="Search on flipkart"]/android.widget.TextView')
e.send_keys("Iphone")

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code in this way

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("your xpath:)
e.click()
e.send_keys("your text")
```

as in your code you are passing null to e